# Can't access dashboard as administrator, login as any other level works though

Tags: admin, login, dashboard

Logging in as admin gets message 'you are not allowed to access this page' logging in as anything else works as normal. Have tried all the usual fixes, disabled plugins/themes restored backup etc no fix.

I have restored access for admins by editing function current_user_can in wp-includes/capabilities.php, hard coding for current administrators. However that's temporary and will be overwritten by any WP update.

What could cause only administrators to loose all capabilities?